# How to make image interpolate to subplot size matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following subplot in my code -

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 6, figsize=(20, 9), sharex=True, sharey=True)

for i in range(6):
    ax = axes[1, i]
    ax2 = axes[2, i]
    ..

    ax.imshow(im_pool, cmap='gray')
    ax2.imshow(get_fft_plot(im_sp[0]), cmap='gray',interpolation='bilinear')

    if not i:
        ax.set_ylabel('Spectral Pooling', fontsize=16)
        ax2.set_ylabel('Fourier Transform', fontsize=16)
```

It prints the following plot:
[image]

All images displayed on ax are size nXn.
The images displayed on ax2 are size pooled images of the original n X n image and hence smaller in size than n X n.These images are not getting interpolated to fit the frame of the subplot even after using interpolation = 'bilinear' in imshow. How to interpolate the images to the size of the subplot frames?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you looking for the `extent` keyword argument of `imshow`?

Comment: @AndrasDeak Thanks a lot, extent does the job. `code`bottom, top = plt.ylim() 
    left, right = plt.xlim()
    ax2.imshow(get_fft_plot(im_sp[0]), cmap='gray', extent=[left, right, bottom, top])`code`